# Inverse Fourier transform of $e^ {-ik^2t}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-transform

I am trying to solve the equation $$iu_t+u_{xx}= 0$$ with initial condition $$u(x,0) = f(x)$$
I solved the equation using Fourier transforms and got $$u(x,t) = \int F(k)e^{-ik^2t}e^{-ikx}dk$$ However I would like to write this in terms of the influence function, using the convolution theorem. $F(k)$ is just the F.T. of the $f(x)$, but I am looking for the function whose $F.T.$ is given by $e^{-ik^2t}$.

I know that if $$F(k) = e^{-ak^2}$$ then the inverse Fourier transform is $$f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{x^2/(4a)}$$In my example can we just let $a = it$? Then the F.T. is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{it}}e^{x^2/(4it)}$. Is this correct?

Comment: wowwowow wait, what is your definition of the (inverse) Fourier transform ? does everything converge when $t$ is real ?

Comment: The last line is rather confusing: do you have **both** $\;x,\,t\;$ as variables?? And before it was $\;k\;$ , when it is *usually* $\;s\;$ ...?

Comment: @Joanpemo : his $t$ is a (real) parameter

Comment: @Dman rename $t$ as $b$ ... thank you. then tell me if everything is convergent, and if you know something about [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation)

Comment: @user1952009 why must I rename $t$?

Comment: $t$ is the time variable in this case

Comment: I have read them and I don't see a reason why I should rename $t$. It is the  time variable, I have added some context to the question a the bottom.

Comment: It's a slight difference in notation, here $x$ is space and $t$ is time and $k$ is $\omega$, this is how I have been taught.

Comment: Notice that if $t$ is real, $F$ is not in $L^2$ - its modulus is one everywhere.

Comment: @T.Bongers please see the updated questions.

Comment: the answer is that with $t$ complex and $Im(t ) < 0$ what you wrote is true by analytic continuation, hence at least in the sense of distribution it is still true when $Im(t) = 0$ (but not when $Im(t) > 0$ since $f(k) = e^{-itk^2}$  is not a tempered distribution anymore). now $\int_d^c e^{-itk^2} e^{ikx} dk$ converges when $c \to \infty$ by  the alternated series test, or integration by parts  $\int_d^c e^{-itk^2} e^{ikx} dk = \int_d^c (-2itk) e^{-itk^2} \frac{e^{ikx}}{-2 i t k}  dk = e^{-itk^2} \frac{e^{ikx}}{-2 i t k}\mid_{d}^c-\int_{d}^c e^{-itk^2}(\frac{e^{ikx}}{-2 i t k})'dk$

Comment: In response OP's question, no.  You can't make a complex substitution to solve a Fourier transform.

Comment: @user1952009, yes, this is standard notation.  $k$ is conjugate to $x$, and $\omega$ is conjugate to $t$.  There is no confusion in notation here.

Comment: @user1952009 I didn't say  I would not do it, I said I don't see a reason to do it since according to my professor that is the notation. I am sure there are different notations, but I don't see why I must adapt to yours if you are unwilling to adapt to mine

Comment: @Dman : that's where you have a problem : read my comments and see where I didn't adapt to your question... so people are here to help you, make more efforts on your side to help THEM. now read my solution answer and tell me what you don't understand (distribution ? tempered distribution ? analytic continuation ?)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i t k^2} e^{-i x k} dk$$
with $x$ real and $t$ real and non-zero. Expanding into the real and imaginary parts yields $\cos(t k^2 + x k) - i \sin(t k^2 + x k)$, which after a change of variables becomes $\sin k$ or $\cos k$ times a function monotonically decreasing to zero, making the integral convergent by Dirichlet's test. So the transform exists in the sense of ordinary functions and is indeed equal to
$$\sqrt {\frac \pi a} e^{-x^2/(4a)} \bigg\rvert_{a=i t} =
\frac {1 - i} {\sqrt 2} \sqrt {\frac \pi t} e^{i x^2 / (4 t)}.$$

This won't be directly applicable here, but to explain why complex-valued substitutions in the transforms can be valid, suppose we know that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a k^2} e^{-i x k} dk =
\sqrt {\frac \pi a} e^{-x^2/(4a)}$$
for $a > 0$. Due to the factor $e^{-a k^2}$, the integral converges uniformly in $a$ on any compact subset of the right half-plane ($\operatorname{Re} a > 0$). This is a sufficient condition for the integral to be an analytic function of $a$ in the right half-plane. The right-hand side is also an analytic function of $a$, and since they coincide on the positive half-line, they're the same function (a similar example is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2692217)).